# how to display the image inside a mp3 file in a image tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, id3-tag, base64url

Hi I was trying to show the image retrieved from a mp3 file in a image tag using html and reactjs. This is the code I used.

```
   async getImageFromUploadedFile(framesRetrieved){
        const imageArrayBufferRetrieved = framesRetrieved[4].value.data;
        var blob = new Blob([imageArrayBufferRetrieved]);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
        var base64 =   event.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
```

when I console the base64 image I got something like this.
[screen capture of the base64 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw7Cl.png)

I tried to show the retrieved image using this code

```
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid item container xs={6}>
                <div id="title"></div>
               <img src="data:image/png;base64,base64"/>
               <div id="audioContainer"></div>
               <div id="lyricsContainer"></div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

But the image does not appear in the tag. There is no console errors. Great if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about getting an image like the album art from the mp3 file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881237/how-can-i-get-the-cover-of-an-mp3-file and this looks helpful https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I get the cover of an mp3 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881237/how-can-i-get-the-cover-of-an-mp3-file)

Comment: Thank you so much I could do it with github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags. I have used wrong reader I guess

Answer (score 1):

I could fix using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmediatags

First you have to install jsmediatags library using `npm install jsmediatags --save`

This is the code that I use to get the image of the mp3

> ```
>   var jsmediatags = require("jsmediatags");
>
>   new jsmediatags.Reader(content)
>         .setTagsToRead(["title", "artist","picture","lyrics"]).read({
>          onSuccess: function(tag) {
>
>   var tags = tag.tags;
>
>   var base64String = "";
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < tags.picture.data.length; i++) {
>     base64String += String.fromCharCode(tags.picture.data[i]);
>   }
>   var dataUrl = "data:" + tags.picture.format + ";base64," +window.btoa(base64String);
>
>   document.getElementById('cover').setAttribute('src',dataUrl);
>     },
>     onError: function(error) {
>       console.log(':(', error.type, error.info);
>     }
>   });
> ```